# Can OpenMP 4 runs target regions in parallel?

Tags: gpu, openmp, offloading

Reading some tutorials from OpenMP 4, I found that `target` regions can participate in the same dependency graph of CPU tasks, using the `depend` clause.

When programming OpenMP tasks, we know they can be run concurrently. But is this possible on GPUs? Can a GPU run multiple `target` regions simultaneously?

I tried with this code:

```c
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i;

#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
  {

#pragma omp task private(i)
#pragma omp target
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("1 %d\n", i);
    }

#pragma omp task private(i)
#pragma omp target
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("2 %d\n", i);
    }

#pragma omp task private(i)
#pragma omp target
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("3 %d\n", i);
    }
  }

#pragma omp taskwait
}
```

Although the `task`s are executed in arbitrary order, the `target` regions are executed atomically, one region at a time.

Comment: Is your goal to run on two different targets? E.g. with a system with two GPUs?

Comment: Nope. I want to run multiple target regions simultaneously on same GPU

Comment: I tried your code with GCC and `nvptx-none-gcc` but it won't compile. If I add `-foffload=disable` it compiles and runs on the CPU.

Comment: I have been able to use the GPU with `-fno-stack-protector` for a few weeks now but in this case it does not compile (segmentation fault compiling).

Comment: are you trying with gcc-8? I'm experiencing same issues

Comment: it works however in a clang implementation

Comment: I am using GCC 7.2 with Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: How did you get the Clang offloading working? I would like to try that

Comment: I installed PGI yesterday but it does not work with Ubuntu 17.10 (due to GCC). The next version of PGI will probably work but that may take a few months (I got the community edition).

Comment: i followed an ibm tutorial (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/8e0d7b52-b996-424b-bb33-345205594e0d/entry/installation?lang=pt_br), but it doesnt works anymore since i upgraded cuda to version 9. I'm trying to recompile at this exact moment